# How to resolve CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser error Uncaught Syntaxerror: unexpected token *

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tradingview-api

Im succesfully embedded my project .Net 4.0 with CefSharp 49, this is my details :
Cef : 3.2623.1401.gb90a3be
Chromium : 49.0.2623.110
.Net Framework : 4.0
Visual Studio : 2010

My project getting error when im rendering web using ChromiumWebBrowser CefSharp version 49. I can't update my .Net Framework because my existing project cannot be upgraded, is there any solution to running my webview using CefSharp 49?

I try to debugging with Devtools and getting that error message

Answer (score 1):

In my case we were doing angular update to 14, when we try to open the app after the update we were getting the same error you mentioned - un expected token error in our console. So we did the following steps to fix this.

1. Update the cefsharp libraries using nugetpackage manager to latest one. In my case i updated **75.1.14** to latest **108.4.130**
2. As part of this update in our code we had code like this after cefsharp.cef.intitalize(settings)

   ```
    CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = True
   ```

And we moved and modified this line of code to the chromewebbrowser initializing method like this

```
     _chromeWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
     _chromeWebBrowser.javascriptobjectrepository.settings.legacybindingenabled = true
```

and then changed existing old usage of _chromebrowser.RegisterAsynchJsObject to

```
     _chromeWebBrowser.javascriptobjectrepository.Register("myAsync", New ChromeBrowserEventHandler(Me),True,BindingOptions.DefaultBinder)
```

Please make sure that your pakcages.config and .csproj are properly updated with new cefsharp versions
and FYI target framework version of our project is .netframework 4.6.2

hope this helps